# R fastest way to convert an entire data table to lower case

Tags: r, data.table, stringi

I have a function written as:

```
setlower <- function(df) {
  for(j in seq_along(df)){
    data.table::set(df, j=j, value=stringi::stri_trans_tolower(df[[j]]))
  }
  invisible(df)
}
```

I have a much larger package that calls this function on multiple `data.table`'s in an `lapply`. The profile for it looks like:

[image: profile]

You can see I spent a majority of my time for each `data.table` I am processing in the `setlower` function. Is there anyway to speed this up? I know both `data.table` and `stringi` are supposed to be about as fast as you can get for `data frame` and `string` operations but I didn't know if there is a potentially faster way to assure that any given data frame is converted entirely to lower case.

Comment: how many unique strings are there, vs total strings

Comment: There's about 295 columns, each with an average of 3-4 unique strings. So maybe about 900 unique strings.

Comment: how about factorising the columns and then lowercasing the levels?

Comment: interesting idea...let me give it a shot.